# How to split a stream in structured streaming without incurring a dual read from kafka

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Our spark streaming app reads different types of events from a single global kafka topic and needs to do a join across two types of event streams. In structured streaming, we are noticing that splitting the input stream based on a filter condition is incurring a double read from kafka since we are unable to cache() the parent RDD before split.

In the past we used the old DStream based APIs to read events from a kafka topic,  apply basic map  operations, cache the resulting stream RDD, and then split the stream into two child streams based on some property (like eventType)

We would then window the streams and do a stream to stream outer join on them.

Our current option is to split our app into two queries,

1. One query to read all events from common kafka topic, and write to different topics based on event type.
2. Second query to read from the two new topics and then call join on them with the approprite watermarks

While this is functionally acceptable, there is additional overhead to intermediate writing and reading from kafka. Not to mention additional topics we are creating.

Just wondering if there are any better ways to solve this?